# What are the IFrames used for in 2021?

Tags: javascript, html, rest, iframe, browser

I stumbled accross an API that is using IFrame to communicate with an underlying third party system. I wondered ok is this just an old system, I noticed the system exposes besides the IFrame a well structured relativly modern REST API. Which made me wonder. Are there any specific advantages for them to use an IFrame instead of REST API ? The exposed functionality through IFrame is Product selection and price retrieval. If there was not an alternative set of REST apis I would have just thought that this is something very old, but now it looks to me as an **intentional choice**.

What may motivate such choice in 2021?

Answer (score 1):

In the education world you have “Platforms” (Learning management systems like Blackboard or Moodle) that are developed to manage online courses.

But the course content maybe developed by separate developers / companies.

So iFrames are used to host 3rd party content within the platform frame.

Answer (score 0):

Few years ago, I was using PHP intensively and did use a lot of `<iframe>` in my pages. The purpose was to use the `<form>` tag along with the `action` and `target` attribute, so forms do not have to be submitted using AJAX, and can be submitted in a *more natural HTML way*, especially when a file is included to be uploaded too. This seems to be a common thing to do, until now. My guess is, the developers behind the website that you described use it to send/retrieve hidden data.

REST is, as it is always explained, is an architecture on how HTTP-based services communicate with each other, including front-end and back-end services. The point of using hidden `<iframe>` like I described is to avoid using AJAX. REST is irrelevant in this case. You can still use hidden `<iframe>` to send data in RESTful way. Of course if you are using `<form>` with `target` and `action`, and also `method` attribute, the data that you send could be in multipart format, not JSON, using POST method. This does not mean REST cannot be used. REST can be used with any data format, including multipart, or even urlencoded.

If the developer uses `<iframe>` in the way that I just explained to you then it could be for the purpose of browser compatibility. You don't need to write JavaScript codes to submit the form. Of course other uses other than form submission exists as well. So using an `<iframe>` *with* REST is okay. Using an `<iframe>` with SOAP, RPC, gRPC, GraphQL is also okay if the data can be formatted correctly. Of course just like you said, it is uncommon. Communication with REST is commonly done using AJAX, WebSocket, etc. `<iframe>` is just one of the component that the developer used to preprocess and send the data to the server. Probably the developer use it to display data or other elements too, but if this is the original intention, this is getting less and less common now and should be avoided due to security issues.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use iframes for media, such as youtube.

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe>` is not an obsolete or deprecated tag. It's still widelly used in the web, mostly for media purposes.

It's also true that a lot of web services have been upgraded not to admit the usage of their services over a frame which they can detect and it's only for security purposes, meaning I'm pretty sure there is a reason why they used or had to use the `iframe` tag on the website you mention.